# Is there a way to delete an alias from an included dtsi file in a dts file?

Tags: linux, device-tree

The file at91sam9x5.dtsi in arch/arm/boot/dts has aliases that are undefined references after deleting nodes that are unneeded using /delete-node/.

Unfortunately if I try to delete the aliases that are now undefined, it does not delete anything:

```
/ {
    aliases {
      /delete-node/ ssc0;
      /delete-node/ i2c0;
};
```

All I could get to work is redefining the alias as something else:

```
   aliases {
        i2c0 = &dbgu;
        ssc0 = &dbgu;
        /delete-node/ ssc0;
        /delete-node/ i2c0;
    };
```

I did a reverse compile, and verified that aliases ssc0 and i2c0 were not deleted.

So is there a way to delete an alias?

Answer (score 4):

OK, I found my mistake.  An alias is not a node.  It is a property.

This works:

```
/delete-property/ i2c0;
```